# PHP MYSQL: Cannot insert data from drop down box and a text box

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data that the user submits from a drop down box and a text box, however this data is not being inserted into my Database Table.

**The Drop Down and text box code:**

```
echo    'Tasks: <select name="selected_task">
                  <option value=""> ---Select ---- </option><br><br><br><br>';

   /*
   Query code to retrieve options goes here and assign it to a variable named '$tasks'
   */


        while ($row_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($tasks))
          { 

        echo  '<option>' . $row_list['taskname'];
                    if ($row_list['taskname']==$select) { echo $row_list['taskname']; }
        echo '</option>';
                  }
        echo '</select>';  

        echo '<div id="task_hours"> 

  <form name="hours" method="post" action="login.php?action=hours"> 
    Hours: <input type="text" name="hours" value="" /><br />  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form> 
</div>';
```

**Database insertion code :**

```
$posted_client = $_POST['selected_client'];
    $posted_task = $_POST['selected_task'];
    $conn_task = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $inserted_time = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskhours) VALUES :posted_hours WHERE taskname = :posted_task ";
    $sp = $conn_task ->prepare ( $inserted_time);
    $sp->bindValue(":posted_hours", $posted_hours, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Make sure you use PDO::PARAM_STR for decimals
    $sp->bindValue(":posted_task", $posted_task, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $sp->execute();
    $conn_task = null;
    echo "Your total time has been entered!<br>";
    echo "Your Total Hours: " . $posted_hours;
```

When the form appears and I click on the 'submit' button after entering data, no error message appears but the number of hours for the table field 'taskhours' is not being updated.

Comment: Are `$select` and `$_POST['selected_client']` irrelevant elements? They're either undefined, or unshown.

Comment: Also, there was a comment about your inputs being outside your form tags; which was deleted. I don't know why.

Comment: $_POST['selected_client'] is from another drop down menu that I'm not using to insert data with at the moment.

Comment: Also the $select variable was what I used for my conditional statement if data is actually present within the 'taskname' table field. Is there a more efficient way of using this while statement to output any data that is found from the database?

Comment: Far as I know, I'd say that's a good way. You could also use `rowCount()` if you want to know if data exists in a particular column; if that's what you are asking.

Comment: You seem to not be assigning anything to `$posted_hours` which should most likely read as `$posted_hours=$_POST['hours'];` as per `<input type="text" name="hours" value="" />` which is part of your bind. May very well be the problem.

Comment: your select condition is not correct. because if 'task = select' you got two values in same option field

Comment: Your query is also not valid -> `"INSERT INTO tasks (taskhours) VALUES :posted_hours WHERE taskname = :posted_task "`. You don't use `WHERE` in an `INSERT` unless you are selecting `INSERT INTO tbl SELECT FROM tbl2 WHERE id=#`

Comment: @JeffP. Sean just found the core problem. You can't bind columns. Why didn't I catch that lol

Comment: Another thing I find really strange; you're using `mysql_` and PDO functions; why? Those two MySQL APIs don't mix together. I think you'd be better off doing a complete rewrite and only use PDO with prepared statements and not `mysql_` functions. There's nothing more I can do to help; good luck. See the following link for examples http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Select>`tag is a Element Of Form So when you use outside form then it doesn't work. so you have put the `<Select>` ('dropdown') is inside the `<form>` then your action page put below code and check you got the data or not in your post method.

`<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
?>`

here you got the all the form data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `select` tag isn't inside `form` one.

Put it inside and it will work.